# Is it possible to create and save related data in an entity constructor?

Tags: c#, ef-code-first, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc-2.1

[This article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/constructors) describes the possibility to have constructors in entity types as of Asp.Net Core v2.1.

And I thought, could it be possible to automatically create some related data upon creation of an entity without writing any code for it in the controller?

Something like this:

```
public class ProjectTask
{
    public ProjectTask()
    {
        // Somehow check if we are creating a new ProjectTask.
        // if (create)
        // {
        Notifications.Add(new ProjectTaskNotification
        {
            IsSent = false,
            ProjectTaskId = Id,
            Task = this,
            TimeBefore = new TimeSpan(7, 0, 0, 0)
        });
        // }
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }

    // Some more properties...

    public Member TaskOwner { get; set; }
    public List<ProjectTaskNotification> Notifications { get; set; }
    public Project Project { get; set; }
}
```

And then I would simply save the `ProjectTask`-entity in the controller, without having to worry about `Notifications`:

```
db.Add(projectTask);
await db.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Can it be done? I don't know either C# or EF all that well, so maybe I'm missing something obviously basic?

Comment: Where is it saving the changes?

Comment: @Tom In the controller.

Comment: I don't think this is a good idea. I wonder what happens when you _read_ data from the database with lazy loading. I didn't test this, but I would expect that the `Notifications` collection contains the related records from the constructor. Which you probably only want on _create_. Regardless the outcome, you shouldn't add logic like this to an entity. It's fine to set default values within the entity, but adding related records is a different level. Since you don't want to do this in the controller, you should create a repository where the business logic can be applied.